# Winsock programming connecting to a public ip

Tags: c, winsock

I am trying to connect to my pc publicly from another computer and it returns `10060` error code from the connect function.

When I `bind` the server with `inet_addr("127.0.0.1")` from the local machine 
and connect with a client with that it works.

I have tried to connect with the server's public ip with the same client code down below, it return `10060` can anyone help?

server

```
#include<winsock2.h>

int main(){
    WSADATA ws;
    SOCKET s, newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &ws) != 0){
        puts("error wsastartup");
        printf("wsa error at %d", GetLastError());
    }

    if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET){

        printf("socket error at %d", GetLastError());
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("socket error at %d", GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("bind done");
    }

    listen(s, 3);
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    char *message = "hello client i got ur message";    

    while((newSocket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET){
        puts("connection accepted");
        send(newSocket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    }

    if(newSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("accept failed iwth the code %d", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    getchar();

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

this is the client

```
#include <winsock2.h>

int main(){

    WSADATA ws;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message = "hello this is a message";

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2 ), &ws) != 0){
        printf("wsa error at %d", GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("wsa done");
    }

    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("invalid socket at %d", GetLastError());
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
        printf("connection err %d", GetLastError());
    }else{
        puts("connected");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to ping to public ip from the machine where you run the client, if yes, you need to check if port where server listens is forwarded in router setting

Comment: `server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); --> server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");` this makes it bind on all interfaces.

Comment: Note; server leaks 'newSocket' on each connection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is with your server.  You are binding it to `127.0.0.1`. This means your server will only bind to the loopback interface, so only clients running on the same machine as the server will be able to connect to the server using this same interface.

If you want your server to accept clients from a public network interface, you have to bind to that interface's IP instead:

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("<IP belonging to the public interface>");
```

Or, you can bind your server to all available network interfaces:

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
```

Or:

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Note that you can only bind to IP(s) that belong to the machine that the server is running on.  If the public IP the client is trying to connect to belongs to a NAT/router, you must bind the server to its local LAN IP that is connected to the NAT/router, and then set up port forwarding on the NAT/router to forward packets from an open port on the NAT/router's public IP to the listening port on the server's LAN IP.  If the NAT/router supports uPNP, your server can setup the port forwarding programmably.  Otherwise, the NAT/router's admin has to setup the forwarding manually.

Comment: "Or, you can bind your server to all available network interfaces" - GOLD! Wish I'd known this piece of info earlier, many thanks. :)

Comment: @enhzflep is that some sarcasm I am not getting?

Comment: nope, it's the comment that goes along with my upvote. I'd never known that I could bind to 0.0.0.0 before and was thrilled learn. :)

Comment: and also, by they way, that still didn't solve the problem, i put the public ip